# Different UIs/templates in one app

Tags: ember.js

Have a situation where I would like to have two types of interface. One is the default application, and the other is a fullscreen mode for login screens etc.

After playing around for a while, I thought I'd try using two named outlets in the application template:

```
{{outlet main}}

{{outlet alternative}}
```

I then have a master template:

```
{{partial "wrapper"}}

{{outlet}}

{{partial "footer"}}
```

Which gets rendered into `{{outlet main}}` by (I'm using Ember App Kit, so the below is equivalent to App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({...):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this._super();
        this.render('master', {
            outlet: 'main',
            into: 'application'
        });
    },

});
```

Now, the issue is when I want to blow away the master template, and have a different look and feel to the page altogether, like a fullscreen login page, with no wrapper/sidebar or footer.

I thought I could deactivate `{{outlet main}}` with disconnectOutlet in my LoginRoute, and just push the new login template to `{{outlet alternative}}` like so:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.disconnectOutlet({
        outlet: 'main',
        into: 'application'
    });

    this.render('login', {
        outlet: 'alternative',
        into: 'application'
    });
  },

});
```

This though, results in `{{outlet main}}` still being rendered (I imagine due to the ApplicationRoute - renderTemplate of LoginRoute doesn't override it?), and the login template renders underneath it (aka, down the page/below the fold).

Does anyone know how to perform this complete switching of UI in Ember?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely possible. Depending on your use case, if you just want to tear down some of the outlets for particular routes, you can use [disconnectOutlets](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_disconnectOutlet).  However, if you want to go more low-level than that and completely swap out the main template that the application is using per route, it's still pretty easy to do. Take a look at [this jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cugih/1/) as an example.

Comment: This is perfect. Been using it the last couple of weeks, run into no issues. Cheers Adam!

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered why there isn't an option for creating multiple application templates myself, but I think you can achieve what you're attempting to do by having your application template simply render a single outlet:

**templates/application.hbs**

```
{{outlet}}
```

And then you could use nested views and components to break up your applicaton:

**templates/main.hbs**

```
{{view 'TopNav'}}
{{view 'Blog'}}
{{view 'Footer'}}
```

**templates/alternative.hbs**

```
{{view 'Blog'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Aaron! I think I experimented with something similar, but I think that when I rendered something with just a single `{{outlet}}` in the application.hbs, that whenever I then went to a different route, the entire outlet was replaced/rerendered, which for 99% of the pages on my site, seems overkill. I suppose I could then put a named outlet called content in the main.hbs and direct most content to that so the base outlet doesn't need to be overwritten every route change? Just on specific routes?

Comment: Yeah you definitely don't want to re-render the entire layout each route change. Looking back at your effort using disconnectOutlet; I think you have a error in the variable names. I haven't used disconnectOutlet and I had to look up to see what it did exactly. This commit on github referenced the function (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2926) and it would seem the right syntax on disconnectOutlet is 'from' not 'into'. If that fixes your issue, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[ember-elsewhere](https://github.com/ef4/ember-elsewhere) is well suited to rending things outside the normal route hierarchy and is recommended in the [Ember docs](https://www.emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_rendering-into-a-render-helper-that-resolves-to-an-outlet).

Create a target:

```
{{from-elsewhere name="my-right-sidebar"}}
```

Anywhere else in your app, declare which component should render in the target -- complete with bound inputs and actions:

```
{{to-elsewhere named="my-right-sidebar"
  send=(component "cool-thing"
  model=model launch=(action "launchIt"))}}
```

More examples here: https://ef4.github.io/ember-elsewhere/